# Selenium Webdriver in Python. How can I get table data after mouseover and perform()?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I don't get the table data after mouseover.

URL: https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/championship/qpr-norwich/Gv9whILT/

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
            

# start chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome('~/DB_football/betexplorer_trading/chromedriver',options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

browser.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/championship/qpr-norwich/Gv9whILT/')
 

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html5lib')

all_bookies = soup.find_all('tr')
 
            
for bookie in all_bookies:
    
    info_bookie = bookie.find_all('td', attrs={'class':"h-text-left under-s-only"}) 

    for bookie_name in info_bookie:
        if bookie_name.find('span')['title'] == "Pinnacle":

            HomeOdds_element_to_hover_over = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[class^='table-main__detail-odds table-main__detail-odds--first colored js-has-aodds']")))
            #Current_HomeOdd = HomeOdds_element_to_hover_over.text
            actions.move_to_element(HomeOdds_element_to_hover_over).perform()
            HomeOdds_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="aodds-desktop"]'))).text
            print(HomeOdds_text)
```

This is the html where I do the mouseover from(only for Pinnacle row)

```
<td class="table-main__detail-odds table-main__detail-odds--first colored js-has-aodds" data-bid="18" data-created="19,04,2023,11,46" data-odd="3.46" data-oid="5lieuxv464x0xf4q3g"><span><span><span><i class="icon icon__increasing table-main__icon"></i> <span class="table-main__detail-odds--hasarchive">3.46</span></span></span></span></td>
```

As you can see in the picture above in id="aodds-desktop" is the table that appears on the web when doing mouseover. But I can't get the data in the table using Selenium Webdriver.  I get a TimeoutException(changed wait time) but i think is because no table is found on XPATH.

```
</table></div></div>
<div class="in-archive-odds" id="aodds-desktop">
<div class="in-archive-odds__in">
<table class="table-main" id="aodds-table"></table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```